# MVC file locations and function locations. PHP Zend

Tags: php, model-view-controller, api, zend-framework, inheritance

I just got a job where i would be working with MVC and they knew i didn't know it but would help me learn. I am fairly confident with my PHP or i was until now and had some questions about MVC but figured i would catch on quickly but this is looking like its more in depth than i expected. And i have a few questions..

1. Is their an easier way to tell which PHP file is a certain class without having to view its contents? Using netbeans.
2. I understand the inheritance of the class that it is extends but some functions access different classes out of the directory they are in and are different from the global included Zend library. Is their a way to find these classes easier?
3. All modules have their own MVC framework with their API and core files for them. Some module files will extend(for example) the Application/Library/Engine/Engine.php. They create and instance and then call a unknown method getApi($param,$param) to the example.php and the class. I cannot find the getApi function in any core class, local classes, or zend. Am i looking in the incorrect places? Can i have a more straightforward view on what the class inherits?

Im pretty lost here but i will keep trying until i figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Zend the Files are names after the class. So Zend_Database_Adpater() is placed in Zend/Database/Adapter.php.
2. I hope answer 1. helps here too. Zend has a search path where it looks for objects.
3. mh... Sounds like you need a Zend Tutorial and a [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) for the start. Normaly you don't need to crawl into the core.

I guess i am not a big help here, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes you are helpful. I see how the path name relates to the files which is very helpful. thanks